# Why does this 'if' condition with io.connect not work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following part of code:

```
var SocketChat = socketFactory({
                ioSocket: (typeof io === 'undefined') ? io.connect('http://test.com:8181') : null
            });
```

I try to check if the `io` object exists as:

```
(typeof io === 'undefined')
```

But I get error `ReferenceError: io is not defined` still.

Comment: read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's write out that ternary statement:

```
(typeof io === 'undefined') ? io.connect('http://test.com:8181') : null
```

Is basically:

```
if(typeof io === 'undefined'){
    io.connect('http://test.com:8181')}
} else {
    null;
}
```

So, if `io` is `undefined`, you're trying to call `.connect` on it.

That doesn't work.

You may want to change your condition:

```
io ? io.connect('http://test.com:8181') : null
```

So, if `io` is a truthy value, `.connect` is called on it.

Comment: You are wrong here: `(typeof io === 'undefined') ? <<---`

Comment: It should be `!== 'undefined'`

Comment: I literally copied `===` from your question. If you replace that with `!==`, that also solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use the condition the correct way. How can it access `io.connect` if `io` is undefined?

```
  var SocketChat = socketFactory({
                    ioSocket: (typeof io !== 'undefined') ? io.connect('http://test.com:8181') : null
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

If `io` is `undefined`, how is `io.connect()` supposed to work? Please change your code to:

```
(typeof io === 'undefined') ? null: io.connect('http://test.com:8181')
```